# Check if the lines of a file contains given pattern without regex in Rust

Tags: string, rust, matching

I'll start by saying I'm new to rust. Actually, this is the first Rust program I'm trying to write.

I'm able to read a (large) file line by line and check which lines contain the pattern  `"PerfectSwitch-0 : Message:"` with the following code:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, prelude::*, BufReader};

fn main() -> io::Result<()>{
    let file = File::open("../test.out")?;
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    for line in reader.lines(){
        let line = line.unwrap();
        if line.contains("PerfectSwitch-0: Message:"){
            println!("{}", line);
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

However, what I really want to do is to modify this code in a way that my pattern could match `"PerfectSwitch-0 : Message:"`, `"PerfectSwitch-1 : Message:"`, `"PerfectSwitch-2 : Message:"`, ..., `"PerfectSwitch-8 : Message:"` and `"PerfectSwitch-9 : Message:"`, **without** a regex.

The reason for this is that I think using regex in this case would be a little bit of a overkill  and it could slow down my program (?).

I've tried writing `if line.contains("PerfectSwitch-?: Message:")` but, non-surprisingly, it didn't work.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: Why is regex overkill? Why do you think it will slow down your program? Maybe it will speed it up! Why not give it a try?

Comment: I'm not sure. As I said, this is my first experience with Rust. It seemed "simpler" not to use regex. But I'll definitively give it a try. If it is possible doing what I want without regex, it would be nice to make some comparisons though.

Comment: I think using a regex for this specific case would be simpler. The standard library has no pattern matching facilities. So you'd either need to roll your own (not simple) or just implement your own little parser (maybe simple, but not as simple as just using a regex).

Comment: Did the answer resolve your question?

Answer (score 3):

I would try `regex` in this case and see if it meets your performance requirements first.

One upside in my opinion is that `regex` is easier to parse and change around when you come to revisit the code.

For example, given the following input to parse:

```rust
let input = vec![
    "PerfectSwitch-42 : Message:",
    "PerfectSwitch- : Message:",
    "Message :",
    "PerfectSwitch-271828 : Message:",
    "PerfectSwitch-314159 : Message:",
    "PerfectSwitch-",
];
```

We could do the following:

```regex
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new(r"^PerfectSwitch-[0-9]+ : Message:").unwrap();

    let result = input
        .iter()
        .filter(|&s| re.is_match(&s))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
}
```

Or write a gnarly handwritten solution:

```rust
fn contains_switch(s: &str) -> bool {
    let mut cursor = 0;
    
    // Return early if the string is not at least as long as:
    // - The length of "PerfectSwitch-" (14)
    // - One or more ASCII digit(s)     (1..)
    // - One ASCII whitespace           (1) 
    // - The length of ": Message:"     (10) 
    if s.len() < 26 {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Match on and consume "PerfectSwitch-"
    if &s[..14] !=  "PerfectSwitch-" {
        return false;
    }
    cursor += 14;

    // Match on and consume ASCII digits
    let digits = s[cursor..].bytes().take_while(u8::is_ascii_digit).count();
    if digits == 0 {
        return false;
    }
    cursor += digits;
    
    // Match on and consume ASCII whitespace
    if &s[cursor..cursor + 1] != " " {
        return false;
    }
    cursor += 1;
    
    // Match on and consume ": Message:"
    if s.len() < cursor + 10 {
        return false;
    }
    &s[cursor..cursor + 10] == ": Message:"
}

fn main() {
    let result = input
        .iter()
        .filter(|&s| contains_switch(s))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
}
```

I'd wager that the first is less likely to contain a bug.

In both cases this should give you:

```
[
    "PerfectSwitch-42 : Message:",
    "PerfectSwitch-271828 : Message:",
    "PerfectSwitch-314159 : Message:",
]
```

### Benchmark

Iterating over 1,000,000 randomly generated lines, benchmarked with [`glassbench`](https://github.com/Canop/glassbench), we get the following:

```
┌─┬───────────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┐
│#│     task      │total duration│mean duration│
├─┼───────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┤
│1│re_is_match    │  2.641099049s│   52.82198ms│
│2│contains_switch│  1.999254015s│    7.37732ms│
└─┴───────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┘
```

With the above results, and the trade-off in maintain- and readability, I would really opt for using the `regex` crate.

Comment: Avoiding the regex crate doesn't seem like a good idea in general, unless you need to keep the binary small. It's a very well tuned crate and often the most efficient (and convenient) solution.

Comment: Also, randomly generated data is probably one of the worst cases for the regex crate. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over all possible values:

```rust
let line = line.unwrap();
for i in 0..=9 {
    if line.contains(&format!("PerfectSwitch-{}: Message:", i)) {
        println!("{}", line);
    }
}
```

Although you probably want to rethink your assumption that regexes are bad. Rust's `regex` library is very fast, and I doubt any small performance gains you get here will outweigh the lack of maintainability that comes with rolling your own parsing code.